# Djnago Rest-Framework JWT Authentication

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

This is register api I am using for the token creation on jwt

```
class RegisterView(APIView):
    
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = RegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            print(user)
            
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
                
            return Response(
                {
                'status':200,
                'message':'Phone Number Registered Successfully',
                'refresh':str(refresh),
                'access': str(refresh.access_token) 
                }
                )
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Then I want to update that record through this api but while using IsAuthenticated it is giving me user_not_found.

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def set_mpin(request):
    phone_number = request.data.get('phone_number')
    print(phone_number)
    
    if not phone_number:
        return Response({'status': 400, 'message':'phone number required'})
    
    try:
        registered_phone = Register.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)
        print(registered_phone)
    except Register.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({'status': 400, 'message':'invalid phone number'})
    

    serializer = SetMpinSerializer(registered_phone, data=request.data)
    print(serializer)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        
        return Response({'status':200, 'message':'MPIN Successfully Created'})
    else:
        return Response({'status':400, 'message':'Invalid'})
```

Anyone can solve this problem?

I want to update that record.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should pass the requesting user's access token in the headers of your request. For example:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.put(url, headers={'Authorization': 'auth_scheme user_token'}, data={'phone_number': 'user_phone_number'})
```

Comment: while i am using first time it is giving me proper response but i am trying to update another user then it is giving me user_not_found in response

Comment: The first time as you mentioned, the API is open means anyone can hit and update the data, but when using IsAuthenticated in the permission_classes, means only the user with is_authenticated = True, has the permission to update. So my suggestion here would be to check if the requesting user is authenticated or not. Then you should pass the Authorization token of the requesting user in the header part as shown above.